# SharePoint: Search box not using search settings

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm having a problem that just randomly occured, and I have no idea what caused this and how to fix it.

So I have a searchbox that is supposed to use my search settings. Here are my current search settings:

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVvxk.png)

[Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onB9D.png)

My problem is that even though I configure my searchbox to use this sites' search settings, it ignores it. Instead of using `/results.aspx?u={searchboxQuery}` as specified in the settings, it uses `/results.aspx?k={searchboxQuery}`

I'm also using a custom Result Source:

```
{searchboxQuery} Path:https://mypage/Pages
```

The searchbox works if you provide exact matches, but if you try to shorten a word, no result is displayed. The result query itself works correctly, displaying all the correct pages, but not with search queries.

Any help would be highly appreciated, it's quite an annoying problem

Comment: Didn't fully figure out how to fix the issue, but having the result part and the search box on the same page seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this a while back.  I ended up using a Search Results template from the Pages library (Publishing needs to be turned on.  Trying to create the connections myself was too much of a headache.

Comment: Where can this be found?

Comment: Go to the Pages Library and click New Welcome Page in the ribbon and select Search Results page.  Paste your results source query here also and I can examine it for issues.